# Validating null value from DataTable row

Tags: c#

I have a simple string variable like:

```
var currentMedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck = "";
```

and I fill it like:

```
var EmployeeMedian = (from DataRow dr in dtEmployeeMedian.Rows
                      select new
                      {
                          MedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck = dr["MedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck"]
                      }).FirstOrDefault();

currentMedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck = EmployeeMedian.MedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck.ToString();
```

But when it comes null it throw an exception of null:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>
> EmployeeMedian was null.

How can I validate that null variable before execute it? Regards

I try with simple if like:

```
 if (EmployeeMedian.MedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck != null){}
```

but it don't works

Comment: You could probably just put 'where !dr.IsNull("MedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck") in betwen your from and select lines. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Null propagation operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if it's C# 6 or above like below which makes sure to only do the operation if the instance is not null:

```
currentMedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck = EmployeeMedian?.MedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck?.ToString();
```

otherwise you will need to put an if condition before accessing those to make sure you are not calling it on a null reference like:

```
if(EmployeeMedian !=null && EmployeeMedian.MedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck != null)
{
   currentMedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck = EmployeeMedian.MedianEmployeeProgressToBackcheck.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Omg, it's the first time I hear about null propagation. It is really cool thing.Thankyou!

Comment: yeah, study little bit about it, the left hand side variable should support nullability for it